# I need to insert the output of TF5 into a TF1 function

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

need some help here.

I'm looking to find a way to insert the output of 5m TimeFrame into a 1m TimeFrame. Any idea how to do it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague - but to get higher than chart time frame data use the request.security() function call. The details are in the reference manual.